How can I play an audio file from within a ZipFile using JavaFX Media and Mediaplayer?
I'm desperately trying to play an mp3 from inside of a zip file.
Right now I'm making a TempFile and copying the data from the audio file in the zip
File songfile = File.createTempFile("audio", ".mp3");
Files.copy(zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntries.get(i)), songfile.toPath());
song = new Media(songfile.getPath());
songPlayer = new MediaPlayer(song);
songPlayer.play();

i cant seem to figure out what to do next, attempts to create a media with this temp file are falling flat.
I have tried to simply create a media with the temp file, but i guess i cant figure out the path for it?
no matter what i do it gives me an absurd amount of errors.
The main problem seems to be the Files.copy. I'm getting a FileAlreadyExists error that seems to be the problem causer.

”It gives me errors”. What did the error messages say the problem was?

That said, the Media constructor you are using is expecting a URI, not a file system path. Without knowing the error message, though, we can only make guesses as to what the problem is.

I think you're suppose to suppling URI not a file path (ie file://... instead of C:/...), so maybe try Media media = new Media(songfile.toURI().toURL().toString()); or something similar instead

Java has a zip file system which can read files in zips.  But it won't work directly with the Media constructors.  You can see supported protocols are file, http, https, jar and hls, not zip.  jars and zips are similar so perhaps the jar protocol would work with a zip file with a correct URL, no guarantee though.  If you have successfully extracted from the zip to a file, try MadProgrammer's suggestion.

@MadProgrammer Hey! this was exactly what I needed! it works perfectly now! Thank You! <3

Ok! There were two issues plaguing this code. The first was that I was supplying the Media constructor with a Path when it needs a URI. This was solved by the following
song = new Media(songfile.toURI().toString());
The next issue was my FileAlreadyExists error. This was also a really simple fix, I just needing to set the CopyOption to REPLACE_EXISTING as following
Files.copy(zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntries.get(i)), songfile.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

Thats it! The song plays perfectly now!

#1 Get the audio file from the ZileFile
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("file.zip");
ZipEntry audioEntry = zipFile.getEntry("path_to_audio_file_inside_zip.mp3");

#2 Get the audio as InputStream
InputStream is = zipFile.getInputStream(audioEntry)

#3 Play it
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(is);
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(ais);
clip.start();


Unlike JavaFX, JavaSound will not play MP3 files, unless one makes use of a third-party provider.
